# Reviewing a 2016 IITJEE problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

IITJEE has been asking novel and interesting problems at ancillary level for engineering entrance in India. A shortcoming occurs rather rarely. In 2016, they asked a MCQ (Multiple choice question) with one or more than one choices correct:

Let $f:(0,\infty)\to R$ be a differentiable function such that $f'(x)=2-\frac{f(x)}{x}, \forall x \in (0,\infty)$ and $$f(1)\ne 1.....(*).$$ Then

(A)$~ \lim_{x\to 0^+} f'(1/x)=1$, $\quad \text{(B)}~ \lim_{x \to 0^+} xf(1/x)=2, \quad \text{(C)} \lim_{x \to 0^+} x^2 f'(x) =0,\quad$ $\text{(D)}\quad |f(x)|\le 2~ \forall x \in (0,2)$

We solve the ODE $$f'(x)=2-\frac{f(x)}{x} \implies xf'(x)+f(x)=2x \implies \frac{d}{dx} xf(x)=2x$$
By integrating we get $$xf(x)=x^2+C \implies f(x)=x+\frac{C}{x}.....(**)$$

Where, usually $C$ determined by a given value of $f(a)$ at some $x=a$. However, here a peculiar condition ($*$) has been given. Using ($**$), we find that the option (A) is correct both with and without the condition ($*$) given by them. Also, (A) option is the official solution.

Here, the question is whether the stated problem  is all right. Your comments are welcome.

**EDIT**: There was a typo in option (A),this particular option has  been corrected now. You may also see [here](https://questions.examside.com/past-years/year-wise/jee/jee-advanced/jee-advanced-2016-paper-1-offline/KUmyTWMyc8dbba7m) for the original source.

Comment: Was option (a) meant to multiply by $x$ in the limit?

Comment: @RollenS.D'Souza In fact, Option (a) was supposed to be $\lim_{x \to 0^+} \mathbf{f'}(\frac{1}{x}) = 1$.

Answer (score 5):

When $f(x)=x+C/x$ with Possibility that $f(1)=1$ , we will get $C=0$ , which makes $f(x)=x+C/x=x$. That Possibility is eliminated with the Criteria that $f(1)$ is not $1$.

(A) limit is $\infty$ : not Correct.
(B) limit is $1$ : not Correct.
(C) limit is $-C$ , which is not $0$ , according to given Criteria : not Correct
(D) we have unbounded $|f(x)|$ : when $x=0.000000001$ , we will get $100000000C+0.000000001$ : not Correct

I think there is something wrong here , though I may be missing something silly . . . .

Might be Printing Mistake / typo . . . .

(Case X) When we change the given Criteria to $f(1)=1$ , then Constant $C=0$ , (C) & (D) will be the Correct Choices . . . .

(Case Y) In Case (A) was supposed to be $xf(1/x)$ , then it will be $1+Cx^2$ which gives $1$ in the limit , then (A) is the Correct Choice.

(Case Z) We have other ways to fix the given typo.
I have been told ( thanks to user "Sarvesh Ravichandran Iyer" & user "Rollen S. D'Souza" ) that (A) was given wrongly & that it involves the Derivative of $f(1/x)$
Then , (A) is the Correct Choice.

Comment: Check the question now.